# Web fonts: how can I specify weight without changing the font family?

Tags: css, webfonts, typography

Webfonts for different weights are in different files, and hence typically appear as a different `font-family`:

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'LatoWeb'; 
 src: url('/fonts/blog/Lato-Regular.eot');
 src: url('/fonts/blog/Lato-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('/fonts/blog/Lato-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
      url('/fonts/blog/Lato-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
      url('/fonts/blog/Lato-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}


@font-face {
 font-family: 'LatoWebSemibold';
 src: url('/fonts/blog/Lato-SemiboldItalic.eot');
 src: url('/fonts/blog/Lato-SemiboldItalic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('/fonts/blog/Lato-SemiboldItalic.woff2') format('woff2'),
      url('/fonts/blog/Lato-SemiboldItalic.woff') format('woff'),
      url('/fonts/blog/Lato-SemiboldItalic.ttf') format('truetype');
 font-style: italic;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

With non-web fonts, I can specify `font-weight: 400` or `font-weight: 200` and have the heavier or lighter version of the font used.

However it seems with web fonts that I would have to change the `font-family` as well as the `font-weight` to change how heavy the font is.

**Can I use different versions of the same `font-family` just by specifying the `font-weight`?**

Or is that not possible, and do sites that use web fonts change the font-family every time they change the weight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to change the font family. In fact you keep the font family the same and just alter the values for `font-style` and `font-weight`. Keep in mind, that the standard font should be mentioned first, as this prevents certain browsers from not recognizing your definitions well:

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'LatoWeb'; 
 src: url('/fonts/blog/Lato-Regular.eot');
 src: url('/fonts/blog/Lato-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('/fonts/blog/Lato-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
      url('/fonts/blog/Lato-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
      url('/fonts/blog/Lato-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
 text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

@font-face {
 font-family: 'LatoWeb';
 src: url('/fonts/blog/Lato-SemiboldItalic.eot');
 src: url('/fonts/blog/Lato-SemiboldItalic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-    opentype'),
      url('/fonts/blog/Lato-SemiboldItalic.woff2') format('woff2'),
      url('/fonts/blog/Lato-SemiboldItalic.woff') format('woff'),
      url('/fonts/blog/Lato-SemiboldItalic.ttf') format('truetype');
 font-style: italic;
 font-weight: normal; /* for a semibold typo, you might want to set a different value */
 text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

So you can reference the font like:

```
.my-font-element {
  font-family: 'LatoWeb';
}
.my-font-element .italic {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you defined the styles in your @font-face the same as used within the usage of the font. So if you have a CSS class using " font-weight: 600; font-style: normal;", you need to have a font-face defined that has these values.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the `font-family`, you don't need to **also** specify the `font-weight` or `font-style`. Instead, you can declare classes for each font variation you are using.

For example:

```
.lato-web {
  font-family: 'LatoWeb';
}

.lato-web-semibold {
  font-family: 'LatoWebSemibold';
}
```

In addition, text in a web font that is coerced into a different weight via `font-weight` may not render as nicely text left at its native weight.